# Init Token Account error - "Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0"

Tags: rust, solana, anchor-solana, solana-program-library

In my program I'm trying to init PDA Token Accounts so that my program can store tokens of specified mints like this:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct StartAuction<'info> {
    #[account(init, seeds=[&state.positions_count.to_ne_bytes()], bump, payer = authority, space = 5000)]
    pub position: Account<'info, Position>,

    #[account(mut, seeds=[b"state"], bump)]
    pub state: Account<'info, State>,

    pub token: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub token2: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(init, payer = authority, token::mint = token, token::authority = position)]
    pub vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    // #[account(init, payer = authority, token::mint = token2, token::authority = position)]
    // pub token2_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}
```

If the `token2_vault` account is commented like shown above everything is good. But when I uncomment it (to have two Token Accounts for different mints), I'm getting a confusing error: **Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0**.

Assuming that this is the `NotRentExempt` ("Lamport balance below rent-exempt threshold") SPL Error as specified [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/ea354ab358021aa08f774e2d4028b33ec56d4180/token/program/src/error.rs#L13) and given that the `authority` account definitely has enough lamports, it's completely unclear why I can init one account but not two, with such strange error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding seeds to the accounts definitions, like this:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct StartAuction<'info> {
    #[account(init, seeds=[b"vault1".as_ref()], payer = authority, token::mint = token, token::authority = position)]
    pub vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(init, seeds=[b"vault2".as_ref()], payer = authority, token::mint = token2, token::authority = position)]
    pub token2_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>
}
```

I guess without defining seeds those two accounts had the same address which caused the error. Why this generates the **0x0** `NotRentExempt` error is still not clear.